# WEKA Java IOException converting csv to arff

Tags: java, converters, weka

I just ran the following code:

```
java -cp ~/prototype/weka-3-9-0/weka.jar weka.core.converters.CSVLoader ~/prototype/honeycsv/cowrie.csv > ~/prototype/honeycsv/testfiles/cowrie.arff
```

And got the following error message:

```
java.io.IOException: 6 Problem encountered on line: 2
        at weka.core.converters.CSVLoader.getInstance(CSVLoader.java:1373)
        at weka.core.converters.CSVLoader.readData(CSVLoader.java:908)
        at weka.core.converters.CSVLoader.readHeader(CSVLoader.java:1213)
        at weka.core.converters.CSVLoader.getStructure(CSVLoader.java:968)
        at weka.core.converters.AbstractFileLoader.runFileLoader(AbstractFileLoader.java:332)
        at weka.core.converters.CSVLoader.main(CSVLoader.java:220)
```

I wanted to test if WEKA runs on its own but since Im running on Ubuntu Server 14.04 dont think that GUI works. Anyways I was always getting an error with regards to display and X11.

So why am I getting this problem? Appreciate

Answer (score 0):

WEKA was getting confused with entries that had a "," in them, thus confusing the "," in entry with "," used as a separator. Thus when matching columns with data entries in CSV file it gives an error.